# Node js doesn't seem to find the index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

Node js doesn't seem to find the index.js file

I am working with node v16.14.2 I have an express project connected to port 3000 that was working normally and out of the blue it no longer starts correctly, the problem started when I tried to run it with nodemon and the only thing I received on consoles was **[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...** no more. Try running then npm start configured in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
     "start": "node ./src/index.js",
     "dev": "nodemon src --exec babel-node",
     "build": "babel src -d dist"
   },
```

With this the console goes blank and then closes. What is happening?

index.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from "express"
dotenv.config();

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());
server.use(morgan('dev'));

let port = 3000;
server.listen(port, err =>{
     if(err){
         return console. error(err);
     }else{
         return console.log(` listening on port: ${port}`)
     }
});
```

Comment: If it couldn't find the index.js there would be a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error. And the "app crashed" error from nodemon indicates, that it found and started your index.js ... Not sure what's going on with your project, but try adding some console output as the very first statement of your script ...

Comment: @derpirscher I have already tried to replace my index.js with a simple console.log() however I still get no output in the console, when I try to do a debug and add a break point in the first line of my index.js it tells me no there is a connection to the file, that is what makes me think that it cannot find it, or that there is a bug in my program.