# express app crashes without returning exception - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

This question is a replica of: [Node js doesn't seem to find the index.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74521640/node-js-doesnt-seem-to-find-the-index-js-file)

I'm working on express version 4.18.2, when I start the server using the path node ./src/index.js the server wakes up for a second and then crashes without throwing any exceptions or error messages, this is my index. js

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const server = express();
server.use(express.json());
server.use(morgan('dev'));

let port = 3000;
server.listen(port, err =>{
    if(err){
        return console.error(err);
    }else{
        return console.log(` listening on port: ${port}`)
    }
});
```

I started a build to debug and if I add a breakpoint in the index.js it doesn't seem to identify the file, could it be an index.js configuration not registered in the node modules?

```
npm start
```

[image]

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "innahealth",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "type": "module",
 "main": "./src/index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./src/index.js",
   "dev": "nodemon src --exec babel-node",
   "build": "babel src -d dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
   "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
   "@babel/node": "^7.20.2",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
   "handlebars": "^4.5.0",
   "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try run `node index.js`, instead `npm start`. Share your `package.json` file.

Comment: The `npm start` command does not have a feature to "find" your starting js file (in your case you seem to name it `index.js` but it can be any name, personally I prefer to use {project_name}.js.. for example ecommerce_backend.js) instead you need to tell `npm` which file to read as a starting point by configuring it in the `package.json` file.

Comment: @yeya I just uploaded my package.json file

Comment: What version of node are you using? What is the result of running `node ./src/index.js`

Comment: @yeya I'm on version **8.5.0**. I managed to fix it by deleting my routes files and generating a test route in the index.js, the real problem here is that the console doesn't show any exceptions or execution errors at code compile time, do you have any idea how I can fix it? ? maybe some json configuration that I am forgetting

Comment: Please upgrade. 8 is out of date. You should use 18.

Comment: @yeya I made a mistake saying that I use version 8.5.0 of node. That's the npm version I just updated to 8.19.1. My current version of node is 18.9.1

Comment: You still didn't answer the question, can you run it correctly directly with node? Without npm start?

Comment: No, I already tried it and it doesn't work